# Android App with Google ML Kit progressively consume more native memory as time pass

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

I'm not able to exactly pinpoint what the issue is. I use Google ML kit to do the face detection on images every 15sec and it runs as a service. My app runs continuously and after 1:30 hrs of runtime the RAM becomes full and the native memory allocation completely occupies the RAM. On the service class side, I properly cleared all references to the FaceDetector object as well as the Bitmap object.

I'm attaching screen shots of the memory, apart from this I do not have any idea what to debug.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone tell me what the issue is or at least point to a direction in which I can debug more? Thanks.

Comment: please post the code if possible